# Codename one Dropbox plugin?

Tags: codenameone

is there any plugin to read and write to Dropbox? I have seen an other post about dropbox but was posted 2 years ago. Is there any change so the plugin can write to Dropbox? Or an other solution like dropbox for example google drive or something else? I ask because I need a solution for an application to backup its data.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The same library is still there although I haven't personally tested that it still works. I know some developers ported it to OAuth 2.x but they didn't contribute the code back so if it doesn't work that might be a problem.

I'm not aware of a similar integration at this time.

Comment: one last question, can i write to dropbox or just read and download the files?

Comment: I think that was the motivation behind the OAuth 2 port. The current lib is read-only and uses a simpler authentication system.